# android- multiple alpha set in xml can't work

Tags: android, xml, animation, alpha

I was trying to make an alpha animation like this:

```
<alpha
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.9"/>
<alpha
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromAlpha="0.9"
    android:startOffset="300"
    android:toAlpha="0.6" />
<alpha
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromAlpha="0.6"
    android:startOffset="600"
    android:toAlpha="0.9" />
<alpha
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromAlpha="0.9"
    android:startOffset="900"
    android:toAlpha="1"
    android:fillAfter="true"/>
```

But my Imageview is not opaque even I set toAlpha = 1 in the end.
Is that because I can only set once  in xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:fillAfter="true">

  <alpha
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.9" />
  <alpha
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromAlpha="0.9"
    android:startOffset="300"
    android:toAlpha="0.6" />
  <alpha
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromAlpha="0.6"
    android:startOffset="600"
    android:toAlpha="0.9" />
  <alpha
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromAlpha="0.9"
    android:startOffset="900"
    android:toAlpha="2.0" />
</set>
```

Comment: It work!
why can set 2.0?
I check Android API and that said alpha property of the view, as a value between 0 (completely transparent) and 1 (completely opaque).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1,0f, 0.0f); 
animation.setDuration(1000); 
<id>.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I tried : 
`Animation animationFont = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_font);`
`ImageView.startAnimation(animationFont);`

but I want the result looks like  0f->0.9f->0.6f->0.9f->1
is that possible in one xml?